# Trouble with android emulator (only Google Pixel)

Tags: android, emulation

I have a problem with turning on the mobile emulator from Google pixel. I have a total of 4 (different ones) and they all turn on fine, but the one I really need doesn't. It keeps loading that G and nothing happens. Just yesterday everything was working without a problem. It always write:

> Time out after 300 seconds waiting for emulator to come online.

Comment: which OS are you using? which Android Studio version are you using? Have you tried to remove/reset the simulator and create a new one? Have you updated all SDK and libraries' versions?

Comment: try cold reboot

Comment: Cold reboot didn't help. Only Wipe data and reinstall my app.